# JavaScript regular expression to extracting title content

Tags: javascript

I want to extract title form the input using regular expression

```
var str = '<a href="http://example/caraft.html" title="Queen Size">'; 
var pat = "title="([^"]+?)";
var result = str.match(pat);
```

Getting output like :  title="Queen Size"

Output need : Queen Size

Temporarily I have achieved by using sub string

```
result = result.substring(6, (result.length-1));
```

I cannot figure a way to do it with regular expression. 

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Look at the quotes in `"title="([^"]+?)";`.

Comment: [`.*?title="(.*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/gI0kA7/1)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out:-** https://jsfiddle.net/ombtkp6p/

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var str = '<a href="http://example/caraft.html" title="Queen Size">';
  var result = $(str).attr("title");
})
```

**JavaScript Solution:-**

```
var str = '<a href="http://example/caraft.html" title="Queen Size">'; 
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = str;
var htmlObject = temp.firstChild;
var result = htmlObject.getAttribute("title")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..Your solution work perfectly..But I want do same using regular expression ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly regexp -- try this:

```
var str = '<a href="http://example/caraft.html" title="Queen Size">'; 
var pat = 'title="([^\"]+)?"';
var result = str.match(pat);
```

Comment: I tried your solution getting output like title="Queen Size",Queen Size

Comment: So to get that you need use `result[1];`

Comment: You solution I tried works file.. Possible to get this in directly by regexp? with out spiting into array..

Comment: Method `match` returns Array or null.
In other words you can use `result[1]` or `var result = str.match(pat).pop();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '<a href="http://example/caraft.html" title="Queen Size">',
    pat = 'title="([^"]+?)"',
    result = str.match(pat);

console.log(result[1]);
```

You have some problems with the quote character (`"`) in your pattern. Furthermore `str.match()` [returns an array containing the parentheses-captured matched results](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Alternatively you can use the Javascript regex syntax for your pattern:

```
var pat = /title="([^"]+?)"/;
```

Comment: You solution I tried works file.. Possible to get this in directly by regexp? with out spiting into array..

Comment: Don't really understand what you want to do, but you could just use `str.match(pat)[1]`.